# Automatically hide other div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
const answer = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
const question = document.querySelectorAll(".question");

console.log(question);
for (let i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  question[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    answer[i].classList.toggle("hide");
  });
}
```

I have a FAQ with questions and answers. The answers are hidden until the question is clicked. How can I make it that when i have a answers showing, it automatically hides when i Click on a other question so only one answer can be showing?

Answer (score 1):

Loop through all the answers. If it's the answer to the current question, toggle it, otherwise hide it.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
  question[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (let j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
      if (j == i) {
        answer[j].classList.toggle("hide");
      } else {
        answer[j].classList.add("hide");
      }
    }
  });
}
```